# Using one variable to input 5 integers C#

Tags: c#, integer

I am using C# and i am trying to find the the average of 5 values but i can only use 2 variables.

How can you input 5 integers into one variable and display the average of said integers

Comment: try using integer array or List<int>

Comment: Do you perhaps mean 2 **integer** variables? You can have variables of classes as well, which would make that a fairly trivial (and somewhat strange) restriction. Although it's fairly trivial with 2 integer variables as well.

Comment: In what scenario would you be limited by the amount of variables like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the input values in a Integer list or array then use the following code

```
List<int> intlist=new List<int>();
intlist.Add(2);
intlist.Add(3);
..
..
var average= intlist.Average();
```

Using [**Average**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399409(v=vs.100).aspx) will computes the average of a sequence of all the integers in the list.

**UPDATE**: or if the case is to use integers only then you need to use the following code (Remember to validate the `readline()` entries)

```
public decimal Average()
{
 int value = 0;
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
  value+=ConvertToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
 }
 return value/5;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=VS.110).aspx) like this:

```
var list = new List<int>(){ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var average = list.Average();
```

using [Average](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb910354(v=vs.90).aspx) you'll get average of all values in list

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.100).aspx) you have all functions of Enumerable, you can for e.g. sum all values with `Sum`

Answer (score 6):

Use a collection like a `List<int>` and the extension method [`Enumerable.Average`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average(v=vs.90).aspx):

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>{ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
double average = numbers.Average();  // 30.0
```

Use `List.Add` to add single integers:

```
numbers.Add(1);
numbers.Add(2);
numbers.Add(3);
// ...
```

Answer (score 3):

What about using array? I think array is one variable in your case

```
 int[] input = new int[5];
        input[0] = 5;
        input[1] = 40;
        input[2] = 15;
        input[3] = 50;
        input[4] = 25;

        int sum = 0;
        foreach(int i in input)
        {
            sum = sum + i;
        }
        sum = sum / input.Length;
        Console.WriteLine(sum.ToString());
```

@up Yeah that's better way!

Answer (score 3):

You dont need arrays, or lists or anything remotely similar. Pseudo-code:

```
private int sum = 0;
private int count = 0;

while (user inputs valid number)
{ 
    sum += userInput;
    count++;
}

return sum / count;
```

Only two variables.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want solution without `List<int>` then here it is

```
 int[] arr=new int[5];
 arr[0]=10;arr[1]=20;...arr[4]=50;
 int sum=0;
 foreach(int x in arr)
  {
     s+=x;

   }
 s=s/arr.Length;//s is average
```

If you want list

```
 List<int> list = new List<int>(){ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
 var average = list.Average();
```